# Подсчёт суммы заказов за 24 часа

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста! My SQL база данных. Есть user, TrxNumber (номер заказа) TrxDate (дата заказа), TrxAmount (сумма заказа).
Нужно  подсчитать сумму заказов для каждого user'а за 24 часа и показать сумму. В идеале, мне нужно вывести все заказы, сумма которых за 24 часа превышает Х величину по useru.
Т.е. если Петров сделал заказ 2023-11-14 10:05:00,то надо проверить были ли еще заказы в течении 24 часов и вывести их сумму.

Comment: GROUP BY + TIMESTAMPDIFF() + HAVING

Comment: корректнее говорить тогда за сутки, а не за 24 часа. Ибо 24 могут быть с 03 ночи но 03 следующих суток, а с датами попроще. Например какой нить индекс по вычисляемому `date(order.datetime), user_id` подошел бы для группировки, но имеет смысл если 24 часа наши это с 00 до 00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - напрямую посчитать нужную Вам сумму заказов user'а за предыдущие 24 часа.

Вариант подсчета суммы заказов в диапазоне от 1 до 1440 минут ранее текущего.

```
select *
  ,(select sum(TrxAmount) from orders o2 where o2.userId=o.userId 
                and timestampdiff(minute,o2.TrxDate,o.TrxDate) between 1 and 1440) prevSum
from orders o
```

Или подсчета суммы заказов в диапазоне от 0 до 1440 минут (сутки, не календарные) включая текущий заказ.

```
select *
  ,(select sum(TrxAmount) from orders o2 where o2.userId=o.userId 
                and timestampdiff(minute,o2.TrxDate,o.TrxDate) <=1440) totSum24
from orders o
```

Если не удовлетворит по производительности или по другим причинам, можно поискать более сложные решения.

Comment: вы уверены что у вас основной запрос из таблицы order а не  users?

Comment: Нужно ли присоединять таблицу users - отдельный вопрос. Можно присоединить таблицу users к результату запроса.